# DiskStation: OpenVPN TLS Handshake error (self-signed cert & defaults)

Tags: networking, nas, openvpn, synology, tls

I have a DS 1813+ (DSM 5 4493 Update 1 - latest) and am having issues setting up OpenVPN:

- DS' 3rd interface is directly connected on a static IP, with the DS firewall set to only allow the VPN app on that interface, blocking all others

  - LAN: `192.168.1.x` (DS connected to it via ports 1 and 2)
  - VPN: `10.8.0.x` (using default server config)

I have it working internally, but when I remotely connect, the handshake fails:

- Log:

  ```
  12:35:10 OpenVPN 2.3.4 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Jun  5 2014
  12:35:10 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014, LZO 2.05
  12:35:23 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
  12:35:23 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
  12:35:23 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET] MY STATIC IP:1194
  12:36:23 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
  12:36:23 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
  12:36:23 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
  12:36:25 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  #See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
  12:36:25 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
  12:36:25 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]MY STATIC IP:1194
  ```
- Config (Windows 8.1 64bit: OpenVPN GUI - latest):

  ```ini
  tls-client
  dev tun
  proto udp

  remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
  dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.2
  redirect-gateway def1

  pull

  script-security 2

  # Self signed cert:
  ca ca-ds.crt

  auth-user-pass
  auth-nocache
  #tls-remote synology.com

  comp-lzo
  reneg-sec 0
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like the server config file.  Can you also post the client config?  Have you generated a certificate/key combo for your client?

Comment: Nope, that is the client config, the server is set to not need user certs (aside from the ca.cert); not sure how to get the file though as I only access it from a web gui. The server has a self signed cert; everything is just default per the Synology setup so I think it is a network issue, but I don't really know.

Comment: Just one additional random hunch - are you running the OpenVPN GUI as Administrator?  If not, right click the shortcut and run as Administrator, see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are two LAN's on Synology NAS, LAN1 & LAN2; make sure that Port Forwarding for 1194 is set against the LAN# that is specified in the OpenVPN General Settings page.